# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_myPrivateFunction' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, reactjs

I am not even sure where the issue is, the only thing I can think of is due to using `.map()` `this` is getting lost in translation. What I have below works as I could hope overall until I start trying to add in the `onClick` which gives me the error in the subject of this post. I need a pair of eyes to take a look and tell me what i did where I went wrong here.

```
var myApp = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Backbone.React.Component.mixin],
    _myPrivateFunction: function (objId) {
       console.log(objId);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (<ul className="list-group">
            {this.state.collection.map(function (system) {
                return (<li className="list-group-item" onClick={this._myPrivateFunction.bind(this, system.objId)}>{system.objName}</li>);
            })}
        </ul>);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var myApp = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Backbone.React.Component.mixin],
    _myPrivateFunction: function (objId) {
       console.log(objId);
    },
    render: function () {
        var that = this;

        return (<ul className="list-group">
            {this.state.collection.map(function (system) {
                return (<li className="list-group-item" onClick={that._myPrivateFunction.bind(that, system.objId)}>{system.objName}</li>);
            })}
        </ul>);
    }
});
```

The scope of `this` is probably changing inside that function/event.